# Is there a GUI program for editing MIDI files on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, midi

Are there any GUI programs available on Ubuntu that can be used to edit MIDI files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may look at:

- [Music editor and MIDI/audio sequencer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/rosegarden/)
- [Free patch set for MIDI audio synthesis](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/freepats/)

Also on the Audacity wiki page it's said that the MIDI support in Audacity is buggy, but there is a list of tools for working with MIDI provided:

- **Musescore** (Cross-platform, Open Source)
- **Tuxguitar** (Cross-platform, Open Source)
- **Rosegarden** (Linux, Open Source)
- **Anthem** (Linux, Open Source, requires KDE)
- **Red Dot Forever** - very simple Windows program that just records to a MIDI file
- Other free Windows/Linux programs

  - **abcmidi** - abc2midi converts abc notation to midi and midi2abc converts midi to abc notation (Cross-platform, Open Source)
  - **midicomp** - converts midi to text file and back again (Cross-platform, Open Source)
- Not linux

  - **Finale Notepad** (Windows and Mac OS X)
  - **Anvil Studio** (Windows) (free version is feature-limited)
  - **MU.LAB** (Windows and Mac OS X) (free version is feature-limited)
  - **Melody Assistant** (Windows and Mac OS X) (free version is feature-limited)

List taken from http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Midi

Comment: Melody Assistant works on Linux as well (natively, of course).

Comment: Unfortunately, those links are broken after the recent push from Canonical towards Snap.

Answer (score 9):

MuseScore can edit MIDI files. MuseScore is already available in the Universe repositories, so you can install it with

```
sudo apt install musescore
```

However, the Universe often contains outdated versions of programs. If you want to have the latest version, you can add the MuseScore PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install musescore
```

The PPA works with all versions of Ubuntu 16.04 and above.

**Update**: the `musescore` package no longer exists in Ubuntu 20.04. However, the similarly-named `musecore3` package looks like it's more-or-less the same thing. Therefore:

```
sudo apt install musescore3
```

I don't know if there are any PPAs for Ubuntu 20.04, but I suspect you could install a SNAP package or a FlatPak package.

Comment: You believe, or you know?

Comment: I'm 90% sure it can. I haven't used it in a while (and I was using windows at the time), but I remember being able to do so.

Comment: I have tested that PPA works on Ubuntu 16.04.  It does work.

Comment: Also, I don't think that MuseScore can edit MIDI files.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond all those already mentioned tools, I'd like to cite a couple more:

- [MidiEditor](https://midieditor.org/) - GUI tool using Qt5.
- [midicsv](https://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/midicsv/) - Converts MIDI files to CSV, preserving all information. (As opposed to [abcmidi](https://ifdo.ca/%7Eseymour/runabc/top.html) which is a lossy conversion.)

Answer (score 0):

I used LMMS to edit MIDI files, it was easy to use unlike other tools because you can see the notes positions on a virtual keyboard. You can delete, move or add notes. It is also possible to delete or move several notes at once with the selection tool.

There is also a list of other tools here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MIDI_editors_and_sequencers